# Get classes names in a div on its click Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the names of classes attached to a `div` on the `div` click:

```
<div class='hello new fun' id="clckBtn" (click)="fireMyEvent($event)">Click me</div>

fireMyEvent(event){
    let elem = event.target;

    console.log(elem.classList)
}
```

Output is `["hello", "new", "fun", value: "hello new fun"]`

Is there any way I can get only the names of classes in an array directly on click, without splitting ***value***

Comment: what about `elem.className`?

Comment: Does elem.classname provide a list of classes attached to elem in array?